# iCloud Sync not working with almost all services in Mojave (Greyed Out)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud

Came into work this morning and started getting errors on a couple apps I have synced my iCloud, such as Notability and SnippetLab. They said that sync had been turned off. None of my notes or snippets were available.

I did not change anything or even reboot my laptop. Worked fine yesterday. But now, when I go to iCloud in settings, almost all the sync options are greyed out and uncheckable. The only ones that I can still select and turn on are Siri, Find My Mac, News, Stocks, and Home. But I can't sync my iCloud Drive, Photos, Calendars, Reminders, etc.

I've been Googling all morning and have not had any luck. So far this morning, I've tried rebooting, I've installed the most recent security update, and I've signed out of iCloud and signed back in. Nothing works.

Screenshot below shows info on my Macbook and MacOS, plus an example of the greyed out iCloud options.

[image: Example and Mac Info]